# Alias throttle to throttling

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tagging

Right now both [throttle](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/throttle) and [throttling](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/throttling) exist, with the larger batch of questions tagged with the [throttle](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/throttle). They seem to be be about the same general thing, and [throttling](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/throttling) seems like a better choice to refer to the concept by.

While that's being discussed, [rate-limiting](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/rate-limiting) should probably be thrown in the mix as being an alias candidate for the same concept.

All of the above tags are sometimes used in conjunction with [network bandwidth tags discussed in my previous question](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/1703/40193), but the concept seems to be distinct and perhaps those tags should be removed.

Comment: I would propose synonyming them *all* to `rate-limiting` as it seems to be the most appropriate and non-ambiguous tag

Comment: Just bear in mind that `throttle` and `throttling` also have non-network definitions. It's something we are sometimes tempted to do to users, bosses, clients, colleagues, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[throttle](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/throttle) and [throttling](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/throttling) are now synonyms to [rate-limiting](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/rate-limiting)